# In restassurred, how to get particular attribute value using its sibling attribute value in json response of api?

Tags: json, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below is my response 
{
        "id": 123,
        "name": "text1"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "text2"
      }
]

I want to find value of id whose name is 'text2'

Comment: JsonPath FTW - `$..[?(@.name == 'text2')].id`, Verified using [JSONPath Validator](https://jsonpath.com)

Comment: @WilfredClement Rest-Assured doesn't use `json-path`. It won't work. Rest-Assured uses `Groovy's GPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Rest Assured uses Groovy's GPath you can use the following expression:

```
String json = "[{ \"id\": 123, \"name\": \"text1\" }, { \"id\": 456, \"name\": \"text2\" }]";
JsonPath path = JsonPath.from(json);
System.out.println(path.get("find { it.name == 'text2' }.id"));
```

The above code will return `456`

It will work only if the JSON starts with an array `[]`